# Replacing lightning connector with usb-c connector in lightning earphones

Tags: usb-c, lightning

I have a lightning earphones, Sennheiser ambeo smart headset.
https://en-us.sennheiser.com/finalstop

The cables are yellowing, and I wanted to replace them, also I got tired of using this on my Iphone only, I wanted this to work with most modern devices with USB-C..

So I thought, could I just replace the whole thing with a 8-core cable with a usb-c connector?

If no, why. If yes, what most likely will fail? I feel like as long as I can connect the wires properly, then there would be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no.

Lightning sends digital data to the headphones which contain a digital to analog converter that makes something your ears can hear. The headphones also negotiate power from the phone to run them.

USB C can have analog outputs and/or digital outputs. These would not be compatible with the digital format of Lightning. Also, power negotiation is completely different.

Comment: but I could I think at least change the cables?

Comment: @JoeyHipolito That is going to depend on how good your soldering skills are, if you can open the headphones without destroying them, and if a similar cable is available. Most cable for headphones is super fine for good flexibility and that makes it awful to solder. My vote for this case is; if it ain't broke, don't fix it.